# Multiply float(7.2) for simpleXML with PHP5.6

Tags: php, oop, floating-point, type-conversion, int

I am trying to do a simple multiplication in an object-oriented PHP project for an XML file.

In the MariaDB, the data is saved as float(8.2). I get this error:

> The object of class ArticlePrice could not be converted to int in [file online...]

```
$item->addChild('price', $article->getPrice(CountryPublic::getByShortCut('a')));
$item->addChild('newPrice', $productPriceNew*1.8);
```

Then I tried to convert it to float (instead of minifloat) like this:

```
$productPrice = $article->getUsualPrice(CountryPublic::getByShortCut('a'));
$productPriceNew = (float)$productPrice*1.8;
```

The message I get is this:

> The object of class ArticlePrice could not be converted to double in

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: write `var_dump($productPrice)` just before line `$productPriceNew = (float)$productPrice*1.8;` What is the output?

Comment: Which line is getting that error?

Comment: It looks like your `getPrice` and `getUsualPrice` methods return class objects, not numbers. Does your `ArticlePrice` class have a method to get the price as a number? You need to call that.

Comment: `ArticlePrice` is not a standard PHP class, we can only guess at how it works.

Comment: always the last line with $productPriceNew is getting the error

Comment: I get this:object(ArticlePrice)#11396 (15) { ["id":protected]=> string(36) "7f01d63a-3f08-480a-b798-c83f6ddbdb94" ["articleID":protected]=> string(36) "65983c99-66e4-4368-9ba7-039dc5e742c0" ["countryID":protected]=> string(36) "31149178-8a2a-4e57-8133-ca12004a59dd" ["price":protected]=> string(5) "13.50" 
and so on. The price is what I need to multiply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you actually try to cast an object into a float.

```
$article->getUsualPrice(CountryPublic::getByShortCut('a'));
```

Your method `getUsualPrice` return an object `ArticlePrice`, you should put a getter on your class `ArticlePrice` to access your attribut `price` inside it and then cast it into a float.

It's the straightforward solution but probably not the most beautiful in term of conception.

if you try something like

```
var_dump($article->getUsualPrice(CountryPublic::getByShortCut('a')) instanceof ArticlePrice)
```

You see that you cast an object in float.

**After your commentary**

```
object(ArticlePrice)#11396 (15) { 
    ["id":protected]=> string(36) "7f01d63a-3f08-480a-b798-c83f6ddbdb94" 
    ["articleID":protected]=> string(36) "65983c99-66e4-43689ba7039dc5e742c0" 
    ["countryID":protected]=> string(36) "31149178-8a2a-4e57-8133-ca12004a59dd" 
    ["price":protected]=> string(5) "13.50"
```

you see that you got on attribut called price.

you only need to do your operation on that attribut not on your object.
you probably have a getter on your class something called getPrice().

The following code will working:

```
(float)$article->getPrice(CountryPublic::getByShortCut('a'))->getPrice()
```

but you probably need to take a moment to think about the name of your method, it is redundant to have two methods called `getPrice()`

Comment: Thank you, but how can I do this?

Comment: `$article->getUsualPrice(CountryPublic::getByShortCut('a'))` return on object ArticlePrice. Add a new method to your object `ArticlePrice` like `getAmount()` that returns your attribute who contains the price. So you can write something like `(float)$article->getUsualPrice(CountryPublic::getByShortCut('a'))->getAmount()`